# Get value of variables outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery sortable, I am getting index value of li and its attribute on change. I want to send the index value and attribute value through ajax. Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      var start_pos = ui.item.index();
      ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
      var li_id = $(li).attr('data-id'), // send this value in ajax call
        var end_pos = ui.item.index(); //send this value in ajax call
    }
  });
});
```

I want to send these values something like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: `${SiteConfig.staticContentBaseUrl}/sortabletable`,
  data: {
    id: li_id,
    position: end_pos,
    _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
  },
```

How can I get access to variable values outside the function?

Comment: You could wrap request in a separate function and call it passing arguments you got inside `update` callback.

Comment: You cannot access a variable outside of the scope which contains it. You could define the variable in a higher scope, but this ,is generally speaking, to be avoided. A much better idea would be to pass values to the required functions. Exactly how you do that in this case would depend on when and how you make the AJAX request

Comment: Make the variables global so they can keep updating accordingly, and then you just send them with their last updated values in your Ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep both functions separate as they are two different jobs actually.

```
$(function() {
  $('ul').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      var start_pos = ui.item.index();
      ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
      var li_id = $(li).attr('data-id'), // send this value in ajax call
        var end_pos = ui.item.index(); //send this value in ajax call
      do_ajax(li_id, end_pos); //do ajax here
    }
  });
});

function do_ajax(li_id, end_pos) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true, //I added this for better user experience if nothing else depends on it.
    url: `${SiteConfig.staticContentBaseUrl}/sortabletable`,
    data: {
      id: li_id,
      position: end_pos,
      _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without exposing any global variables.

```
$(function() {
   var li_id, end_pos;
   $('ul').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
  var start_pos = ui.item.index();
  ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
},
update: function(event, ui) {
  var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
  li_id = $(li).attr('data-id'), // send this value in ajax call
  end_pos = ui.item.index(); //send this value in ajax call
}
 });
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
   url: `${SiteConfig.staticContentBaseUrl}/sortabletable`,
   data: {
     id: li_id,
  position: end_pos,
  _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
}
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare them outside the function, then assign them inside the function:

```
var li_id, end_pos;

$(function() {
  $('ul').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      var start_pos = ui.item.index();
      ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
      li_id = $(li).attr('data-id'), // send this value in ajax call
      end_pos = ui.item.index(); //send this value in ajax call
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: `${SiteConfig.staticContentBaseUrl}/sortabletable`,
    data: {
      id: li_id,
      position: end_pos,
      _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes sorry @RoryMcCrossan, I will fix that.